Stripe Destination Charges wrong output in Payment details
I'm using Stripe Connect destination charges on charging a client but the output in Stripe dashboard payment details is not the same on the example provided in the documentation.
The image below is provided in the Documentation

The example shows a $10 charge. The $10 charge is then deducted with $1.23 for the application fee for the sum of $8.77 which will go to the connected account or merchant.
The Application fee of $1.23 will then be deducted from the stripe fee which is $0.59 (2.9+%30cents of the charge) amounting to $0.64.
I used the example curl code below to run the process but the output in the stripe dashboard is not the same as the example flow provided.
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions \
  -u "sk_test_51LPByuBJiyP9Bsbcf887kxitVgP93...................:" \
  -d "line_items[0][price_data][currency]"=usd \
  -d "line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]"=T-shirt \
  -d "line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]"=1000 \
  -d "line_items[0][quantity]"=1 \
  -d "payment_intent_data[application_fee_amount]"=123 \
  -d "payment_intent_data[transfer_data][destination]"="acct_1PDLxkB4xpDA109n" \
  -d mode=payment \
  --data-urlencode success_url="https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"

Below is the output in the stripe dashboard.

As you can see the net is different from the example provided in the stripe documentation. Is it the net for the platform account or the connected account? If it's for the platform account it should be $0.64, not $9.41, or if it's for the connected account it should be $8.77.
Is there anything in the stripe dashboard that I need to configure or maybe I just misunderstood the payment details?

The is net of fees, but you need to consider the transfer & application fee too. You should talk to Stripe support about this: https://support.stripe.com/contact

@NolanH this is from stripe documentation.
payment_intent_data[application_fee_amount] - This parameter specifies the amount your platform plans to take from the transaction. The full charge amount is immediately transferred from the platform to the connected account that’s specified by transfer_data[destination] after the charge is captured. The application_fee_amount is then transferred back to the platform, and the Stripe fee is deducted from the platform’s amount. Based on the documentation this is already programmatically deducted in stripe API.


You charged your customer $10.00


+10


Stripe fees are $0.59


-0.59 = 9.41 > This is the net amount on the Stripe Dashoard


The full $10.00 are transferred to your connected account


-10 = -0.59


An application fee of $1.23 is reclaimed from your connected account


+1.23 = 0.64

Your straight profit as a platform for this charge is $0.64
At the end of this:

Your customer was charged $10.00
Your platform made $0.64
Your connected account made $8.77
Stripe made $0.59


Thank you for your answer. where can I see the 0.64 that went to the platform in the stripe dashboard?

You can't. You could infer it by exporting your transactions and totaling the Net amounts. Not sure Stack Overflow is intended to help you navigate an application's dashboard.

If that's the case then there is no way for the platform owner to know or monitor how much money he/she made in the stripe dashboard. The platform owner has to manually calculate all the earnings.

Earnings come in the form of Payouts, which come from the Stripe Balance. You can see what your profit is via those resources, but they're not really transaction-specific. So it's easy to see what your earnings are, but not so easy for one single payment, as it also involves a transfer and application fee which are separate from the payment.
